# Custom C++ code checker for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-analysis, visual-studio-2017

Microsoft has now released the RC for Visual Studio 2017: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-2017-rc/

This version of VS comes with some enhanced static code analysis, checking the code against the C++ core guidelines: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/12/cppcorecheck/

Seems like these checks are implemented as some kind of extension to Visual Studio. Does anyone know if we are able to write our own code analyzers / implement checkers for our own guidelines with Visual Studio 2017? So far we had to use some external compiler (like clang) to generate the AST. I could only find documentation for VS2015, describing how to write custom checkers for managed languages like C#.

Comment: You are probably better off asking them directly on their blog for this. They also are active in the cpp subreddit quite a bit so you can ask them there too. They also really like feedback on those things so asking them may gives them the idea for providing this later on if it's not already there.